# Change Version icon doesn't appear

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I created an ArcSDE geodatabase via create enterprise database tool. I used MSSQL Server. But normally there has to be an icon which is exactly the same one left side of  "SLK sql to sa.sde" text under the layers. You know, underlined of database icon.  Because in the past, when I dropped the feature class, there was that icon which can be selected version user type ( Default, child etc. ) but know there is only a layer and just like ordinary feature class. I want to select version ( child /parent ) but there is no selection.

What is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under where it says "Table of Contents" there is a row of icons - you see you have the first one selected.  Click on the second icon, called "List by Source"

[image]

The Table of Contents pane will change to include the database connection icon.  You can then right-click and select Change Version.

[image]

Comment: Hi sir, Thank you so much :) I thought that it's always been selected list by source. Anyway thank you again.